# What is the correct name for IEEE Std 1003.1, 2004 Edition: POSIX.1-2001 or POSIX.1-2004?

Tags: posix, standards

I came across two POSIX documents online.

- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/ (IEEE Std 1003.1, 2004 Edition)

  > **Abstract:** The 2004 edition incorporates Technical Corrigendum Number 1 and Technical Corrigendum 2 addressing problems discovered since the approval of the 2001 edition. These are mainly due to resolving integration issues raised by the merger of the Base documents.
- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/ (IEEE Std 1003.1™, 2013 Edition)

  > **Abstract:** POSIX.1-2008 is simultaneously IEEE Std 1003.1™-2008 and The Open Group Technical Standard Base Specifications, Issue 7. This 2013 Edition includes IEEE Std 1003.1-2008/Cor 1-2013 incorporated into IEEE Std 1003.1-2008 (the base document). The 2013 edition incorporates Technical Corrigendum 1 addressing problems discovered since the approval of the 2008 edition.

I want to know whether the first document is known as POSIX.1-2001 or POSIX.1-2004.

The [Wikipedia article on POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) mentions the first one as POSIX.1-2004. But why? The base document of the first one is 2001 edition. So shouldn't it still be called POSIX.1-2001? The 2004 edition only adds TC1 and TC2 to the base document.

For example, see the second one. Although it is 2013 edition but since the base document is 2008 edition, it is called POSIX.1-2008. Then why is the first one not called POSIX.1-2001?

Answer (score 4):

From [`standards(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/standards.7.html):

> [POSIX.1-2001] was a 2001 revision and consolidation of the POSIX.1,
>                 POSIX.2, and SUS standards into a single document, conducted
>                 under the auspices of the Austin Group.
>   [...]
>   Two Technical Corrigenda (minor fixes and improvements) of the
>                 original 2001 standard have occurred: TC1 in 2003 (also known
>                 as POSIX.1-2003), and TC2 in 2004 (also known as
>                 POSIX.1-2004).

That is, *POSIX.1-2001 TC2* and *POSIX.1-2004* are both correct names.

Referring to the standard as *POSIX.1-2001*, without specifying the TC level, might be misleading, because it is unclear whether the latest or original version is meant. (It is noteworthy though that technical corrigenda are [intended for clarification of ambiguities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Organization_for_Standardization#cite_ref-ISOUS95IECUS95directives2004_19-3) and not for major revisions of a standard. So unless the context implies that someone refers to the original version, the latest one will probably be meant.)

Comment: Looks like http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/ (IEEE Std 1003.1™, 2013 Edition) may then be called POSIX.1-2013 because `man standards` mentions `POSIX.1-2008, SUSv4: ... Technical Corrigendum 1 (minor fixes and  improvements)  of  this standard was released in 2013 (referred to as POSIX.1-2013).`

Comment: It is not clear to me why POSIX.1-2008 + TC1 is not known as POSIX.1-2013 but POSIX.1-2001 + TC1 + TC2 is known as POSIX.1-2008. Can you clarify why POSIX.1-2008 + TC1 is not known as POSIX.1-2013? As per your answer, POSIX.1-2008 + TC1 should be called POSIX.1-2013.

Comment: It is, as you have stated yourself in your first comment. What makes you think that it was not?

Answer (score 1):

Both the wikipedia article and the [`standards(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/standards.7.html) manual page (which I wrote) are (were) wrong. "POSIX.1-2004" is not an official standard name. (Neither is "POSIX.1-2013".) I confirmed this with one of the core participants in The Open Group. I've just recently amended the `standards(7)` page to remove the term "POSIX.1-2004", and edited the [Wikipedia article on POSIX.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)